# struct value in different C standards

Tags: c, struct

what should print this C code in different C standards?

```
struct X { int a; char b[4]; };

struct X x, y; struct X *px;

printf("%x %x\n", x, &x);   // what mean x in this context?  suppose we get 0x12b45 and 0x34235
printf("%d\n", x == 0x12b45 ? 1 : 0)
px = &x;
x = *px;
printf("%x %x\n", x, *px);
x = y
printf("%x %x\n", x, y);
```

in other ways, what is the value of a struct? or better said, what value a struct resolve to? using an analogy with arrays, an array name resolves to the value of first array item, what value resolves to the struct name?

```
int a[3];

printf("%x %x\n", a, a[0]);  // prints the same value twice

struct s { int a; } b;

printf("%x\n", b);  // what value is printed?
```

@David Grayson asked for a minimal reproducible example, here you are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct X { int a;  char b[4]; };

struct X x, y; struct X *px;

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%x %x\n", x, &x);   // what mean x in this context?  
    printf("%p %p\n", x, &x);  
    px = &x;
    x = *px;
    printf("%x %x\n", x, *px);
    x = y;
    printf("%x %x\n", x, y);
    
    int a[3];

    printf("%x %x\n", a, &a[0]);  // prints the same value twice

    struct s { int a; } b;

    printf("%x %x\n", b, b.a);  // what value is printed?
}
```

I removed the line with the `?`/`:` operator because it doesn't compile with an error about trying to operate with a struct.

Compiled with TCC the result of this code is this:

```
0 402168
0000000000000000 0000000000402168
0 0
0 0
14feac 14feac
6 6
```

my understanding of the results is this, of course printing a pointer or an hex number provides de same value, only formatted differently, so I will disregard the pointer output.

- first print shows `0` and a number which is the address of the `x` variable
  (a struct X), the "strange" thing is the first `0`, I think is the
  value of a member of struct X, initialized to 0 because x is a global variable.
- second print prints the same value `0` because its the same `x` variable, accessing by its own id and by a pointer pointing to the `x` variable.
- third print prints the same value even when printing two different
  struct X variables, `x` and `y`, because I have assigned variable `y`, a
  struct X, to variable `x`, previously so they both are the same
  variable and it's initialized to `0` because is global, but the
  question is, when assigned a struct to another struct, does it copy
  all bytes or simply assign pointers?
- fourth print involves printing an array with the usual behaviour
- fifth print is interesting since it's printing the struct as a whole
  and the first (and only) member, and it prints the same value, 6.
  Why 6?  my guess is this time the struct variable b is a local
  variable and thus not initialized so we get garbage.  The point here
  is using the struct variable appears to be the same as using the
  first member, analogous to array but I don't know if this is standard
  behaviour or it depends on compiler or C standard.

So my guess is using a struct variable as symbols resolves to the same value as first member of the struct, in a similar way of how arrays work. This is aligned to what @Eric Postpischil said, I think.

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile with any recent C standard because `x == 0x12b25` is not valid.  Also, you didn't define a `main` function.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Tip: To print an address (or the value of a pointer) use `%p`, the correct format specifier.

Comment: A structure does not have a numerical value. Its value is, conceptually, an ordered tuple of the values of its members. There is no `printf` conversion for it.

Comment: I was showing only the relevant code, assuming all necessary includes and functions, specially main,  but since you ask for a reproducible example, I include it in my reply

Comment: You haven't posted a reproducible example. If you had, I'd be able to copy-and-paste it and compile it on my own system. That means including any required `#include` directives and a definition of the `main` function. In any case, passing a struct value to `printf` has undefined behavior. With a `%x` format, the corresponding argument *must* be of type `unsigned int` (or possibly `int`). See also [mre].

Comment: The *address* of a struct object is the same memory location as the address of its first member, but it's still the address of the entire object, of type `struct X*`. The *value* of a struct object is the value of the entire object, just as for any type of object.

Answer (score 6):

The C standard does not formally define the value of a structure, although a structure must have a value because some of the behaviors specified by the standard require it, such as assigning the value of one structure object to another. A structure type is a sequence of members, so the value of a structure is conceptually a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) of the values of its members.

The following refers to the C 2018 standard. I expect there is no significant variation in other versions of the standard.

> `printf("%x %x\n" , x, &x);   // what mean x in this context?  suppose we get 0x12b45 and 0x34235`

The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard because `%x` is specified to take an `unsigned int` argument (7.21.6.1 8), and “… If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined” (7.21.6.1 9).

> `printf("%d\n" , x == 0x12b45 ? 1 : 0)`

Compiling this code must yield a diagnostic message because it violates the constraints for `==` in 6.5.9 2:

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have arithmetic type;
>
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
>
> — one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`; or
>
> — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

If the compiler does accept the expression, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

> `px = &x;`
> `x = *px;`

After setting `px` to point to `x`, this merely sets `x` to its own value.

> `printf("%x %x\n" , x, *px);`

The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard, as explained above.

> `x=y`

This sets `x` to have the value of `y` (to the extent it has one; discussing uninitialized objects is beyond the scope of this answer). Immediately after its execution, each member of `x` will have the value of the corresponding member of `y`. Any padding bytes in `x` and `y` may differ, as contents of the padding bytes in `x` are unspecified per 6.2.6.1 6.

> `printf("%x %x\n" , x, y);`

The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard, as explained above.